# Can Personal Access Token with limited scope be shared with other users?

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, access-token, github-actions

I'm building a CLI which triggers an Action (using `workflow_dispatch`) in my repository. I'm using Github API to perform this task. Taken from the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event):

> You must authenticate using an access token with the repo scope to use this endpoint.

I've generated a PAT with `repo` scope to authenticate myself. I want users to run this CLI. Is it safe to share this PAT (which has `repo` as the only scope)?

p.s. I know it is ironical to ask if "Personal"-access-token can be "shared". But I don't see any problem it can cause with its limited scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is a good idea. Repo scope is not limited to only one repo.

If you want to trigger actions by external users, your best bet would probably be to create a workflow running on PR or Issue events.

- Allow your users to create issues
- Monitor keywords or label on the issue
- Trigger your action.